# How to increment current index in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios6

How to increment currentindex so that textview can be updated in a sequence manner than randomly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"String1",@"String2",@"String3",@"String4", @"String5",..... nil];  

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateText:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];

self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville-Bold" size:22];

self.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.textView.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.textView.text = @"String1";
self.textView.scrollEnabled = NO;

self.textView.editable = NO;

self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

[baseView addSubview: self.textView];

} 

- (void)updateText:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
int index = arc4random() % [myArray count];
myTextView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

}

Comment: If you don't want it updated randomly, don't use arc4random!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making index a local variable, make it a property

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger index;

in viewDidLoad initialize it to 0;

Then use it like this only:

```
           - (void)updateText:(NSTimer *)theTimer 
        {
            NSLog(@"myArray count is %d",[myArray count]);
            CFShow((__bridge CFTypeRef)(myArray));

            if (index < [myArray count])
            {
                NSLog(@"%d value is %@",index,[myArray objectAtIndex:index]);
                myTextView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
                index++;
            }
            else
                index = 0;
            }
    }
```

and i hope you are using Timer like this :

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourFunctionToUpdateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: i tried but still it is not updating textview

Comment: can you mail me code i will look it for you, bhupendra.trivedi14@gmail.com

Comment: and are you sure that this updateText function is getting called again and again, set a breakpoint and check if its getting called or not

Comment: yes it is getting called again and again

Comment: can you mail me the code now i will have a look at it :)

Comment: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateText:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES]; i have this nstimerwhich will call update text but i dont think this is the problem for sure

Comment: okay then check if your textView is not nil, have you created textView in xib file or through code, if you have created it in xib file then please check the connections

Comment: i created through code but it is showing string1 though but not updating to string2

Comment: please look at the edited answer and use NSLog to know what values are you getting and let me know.

Comment: not getting any values though

Comment: by adding breakpoint i found it is not stopping at self.textView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
        index++; within the update text function

Comment: it means you are loosing the array values. did you declare myArray as @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray; in .h file and initialize in viewDidLoad of .m file ?

Comment: i cleaned and analyzed it and now getting deadstore for value stored to myArray during its init is never read and unused variable myArray

Comment: i added myArray property forget to write this in my previous comment

Comment: soo is it working fine now ?

Comment: i just added my post please check. it is still not working

Comment: you have used Repeats:NO in the timer .. so it will be called only for once now ???

Comment: I replaced it with yes but still if i add breakpoint it is not stopping at self.textView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
        index++; why is that

Comment: i think because once i initialized my array then i m not telling it to use anywhere only in update text function i m using myArray

Comment: check my edited answer and use the new NSLog and CFShow to see whats happening actually

Comment: it is always showing myArray count is o

Comment: okay that means array is not retained.

Comment: As I already said make it a property @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *myArray and then use self.myArray while accessing values from it

Comment: still myArray count is 0 not inreased

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23392/discussion-between-bhupendra-and-user1452248)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
int index =+1;
```

i've tried this in another app and it worked, so it should for you

Comment: i tried int index = +1; mytextView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index]; but it is not updating String1 with String2

Comment: I'm hoping you were being facetious.  @user1452248 -- Learn about this thing called "program state".